# JSP Vars Returning null when trying to connect to jdbc derby

Tags: java, html, jsp, jdbc

Just some background: I am using Netbeans and created a database called projectdb with the table products which has the columns productid, price, description.

I created a new java class which connects to the database and stores the price and description values depending on what product id the user enters.

Code for that java class:

```
public class ConnectDB{

    String desc, sql;
    double price;
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:####/ProjectDB";

    //start the database connection
    public void startConn(int prodID){
        String d; double p;

        try{

           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "username","password");
           sql = "SELECT * FROM NBUSER.PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTID = "+ prodID;
           Statement st = conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs;
           rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
           while(rs.next()){
            p = rs.getDouble("PRICE");      
            d = rs.getString("DESCRIPTION");
            setDesc(d);
            setPrice(p);
           }
           rs.close();
           st.close();
           conn.close();

        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setDesc(String ds){
        desc = ds;
    }

    public void setPrice(double pc){
        price = pc;
    }

     public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    } 


}
```

Then, I am trying to get the info from that class to display in html. However, it returns null for the string variable and 0.0 for the double variable.

Code for that:

```
<%
                   String desc;
                   double price;
                   DBConnect.ConnectDB cdb = new DBConnect.ConnectDB();                    
                   cdb.startConn(0001);                       
                   desc = cdb.getDesc();
                   price = cdb.getPrice();                       
                 %>
             <a href="#" class="item">                    
                <img src="Pictures\DrkGrySweater.jpg"/>
                <p><%= desc %></p>
                <p>Price:$<%= price %></p> 
             </a>
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Comment: @brano when i try to run the class specifically it says "Class "ConnectDB" neither has a main method nor is it a servlet specified in web.xml" ...

Comment: @brano I added <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>ConnectDB</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>DBConnect.ConnectDB</servlet-class> 
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>ConnectDB</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/ConnectDB</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
into my web.xml and now that error isnt showing up. But that still doesnt fix my problem that i'm getting null and 0.0 returned

Comment: Try by loading derby driver: `Class.forName(org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver);` I can't tell precisely since there are no any exceptions.

Comment: @brano where would that be piece of code be placed?